# Java Servlet how to get the json response from Shopify API

Tags: java, servlets

I was trying to get the products record from shopify API through REST services. But I was getting this error `{"errors":{"product":"can't be blank"}}` Below is the snippet of the code.

```
            String getURL = "https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json";

            url = new URL(getURL);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application-json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Shopify-Access-Token",token);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // Send request
            DataOutputStream w = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            w.flush();
            w.close();


            // Get Response
            InputStream i = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i, "UTF-8")); 
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(inputStr);
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
            }
```

Comment: error message suggests you are not passing product id/code for which you need product information. looks like its expecting some input in the request.

Comment: It should be no need parameter because if I directly paste the url into browser it can access

Answer (score 0):

The Request Headers should be this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Hi even I added the 2 lines, I still got this error {"errors":{"product":"can't be blank"}}

Comment: Did you remove the old line of "Content-Type" setting?

Comment: Yes removed already, if directly paste the link I can access the data.